# Access the key of a multilevel JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a json file which looks like:

```
{
    "ancestors": [
        {
            "subcategory": [
                {
                    "key": "city",
                    "name": "City"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Da Lat"
        },
        {
            "subcategory": [
                {
                    "key": "province",
                    "name": "Province"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Lam Dong Province"
        },
        {
            "subcategory": [
                {
                    "key": "country",
                    "name": "Country"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Vietnam"
        }
    ],
}
```

The problem is that I need to access the name of that subcategory whose key is province.

Here i want to access "Lam Dong Province"

I cant figure out how to go up one level and check the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next` with a generator comprehension.

```
res = next(i['name'] for i in json_dict['ancestors'] if
           i['subcategory'][0]['key'] == 'province')

# 'Lam Dong Province'
```

To construct the condition `i['subcategory'][0]['key']`, you need only note:

1. Lists are denoted by `[]` and the only element of a list may be retrieved via `[0]`.
2. Dictionaries are denoted by `{}` and values may be retrieved via `[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over it, check for the condition you want. If the condition is true, return the value you want.

```
def search_subcategories(json_dict):
    for element in json_dict['ancestors']:
        if element['subcategory'][0]['key'] == 'province':
             return element['name']
```