# Extracting Key from multilevel (scraped) complex structure json file in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a multilevel/complex json file - twitter.json and I want to extract ONLY the author ID from this json file.

This is how my file 'twitter.json' looks:

```
[
[
    {
        "tweets_results": [
            {
                "meta": {
                    "result_count": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "youtube_link": "www.youtube.com/channel/UCl4GlGXR0ED6AUJU1kRhRzQ"
    }
],
[
    {
        "tweets_results": [
            {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "author_id": "125959599",
                        "created_at": "2021-06-12T15:16:40.000Z",
                        "id": "1403732993269649410",
                        "in_reply_to_user_id": "125959599",
                        "lang": "pt",
                        "public_metrics": {
                            "like_count": 0,
                            "quote_count": 0,
                            "reply_count": 1,
                            "retweet_count": 0
                        },
                        "source": "Twitter for Android",
                        "text": "⌨️ Canais do YouTube:\n\n1 - Alexandre Garcia: Canal de Brasília"
                    },
                    {
                        "author_id": "521827796",
                        "created_at": "2021-06-07T20:23:08.000Z",
                        "id": "1401998177943834626",
                        "in_reply_to_user_id": "623794755",
                        "lang": "und",
                        "public_metrics": {
                            "like_count": 0,
                            "quote_count": 0,
                            "reply_count": 0,
                            "retweet_count": 0
                        },
                        "source": "TweetDeck",
                        "text": "@thelittlecouto"
                    }
                ],
                "meta": {
                    "newest_id": "1426546114115870722",
                    "oldest_id": "1367808835403063298",
                    "result_count": 7
                }
            }
        ],
        "youtube_link": "www.youtube.com/channel/UCm0yTweyAa0PwEIp0l3N_gA"
    }
]
]
```

I have read through many similar SO questions (including but not limited to):

- [Access the key of a multilevel JSON file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600755/access-the-key-of-a-multilevel-json-file-in-python)
- [Multilevel JSON Dictionary - can't extract key into new dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140203/multilevel-json-dictionary-cant-extract-key-into-new-dictionary)
- [How to extract a single value from JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response)
- [how to get fields and values from a specific key of json file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483625/how-to-get-fields-and-values-from-a-specific-key-of-json-file-in-python)
- [How to select specific key/value of an object in json via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138775/how-to-select-specific-key-value-of-an-object-in-json-via-python)
- [Python: Getting all values of a specific key from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534662/python-getting-all-values-of-a-specific-key-from-json)

But the structures of those jsons are pretty simple and when I try to replicate that, I hit errors.

From what I read, `contents.tweets_results.data.author_id` is how the reference would go. And I am loading using `contents = json.load(open("twitter.json"))`. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Both @sammywemmy's and @balderman's code worked for me. I accepted @sammywemmy's because I used that code, but I wanted to credit them both in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has a path to it, You've got a list nested in a list, within the inner list, you have a tweets_results key, whose values is a list of dicts; one of them has a `data` key, which contains a list/array, which contains a dictionary, where one of the keys is `author_id`. We can simulate the path (sort of) as : `'[][].tweets_results[].data[].author_id'`

A rehash sort of : Hit the First list, then the inner list, then access the `tweets_results` key, then access the list of values; within that list of values, access the `data` key, within the list of values associated with `data`, access the `author_id`:

With this path, one can use `jmespath` to pull out the author_ids :

```py
# pip install jmespath
import jmespath
              # similar to re.compile
expression = jmespath.compile('[][].tweets_results[].data[].author_id')
expression.search(data)
['125959599', '521827796']
```

jmespath is quite useful if you want to build a data structure from nested dicts; if however, you are only concerned with the values for `author_id`, you can use nested_lookup instead; it recursively searches for the keys and returns the values:

```py
# pip install nested-lookup
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup
nested_lookup('author_id', data)
['125959599', '521827796']
```

Comment: A small follow up. So this is how I have loaded my json:
```with open("twitter.json"), 'r', encoding="utf8") as f: contents = json.load(f)``` Should I just ```nested_lookup('author_id', contents)```?

Comment: yes; do verify that `contents` is indeed a dictionary

Comment: How do I verify that? For me, ```contents``` seems to be a list. (You said it with more elaboration dictionary inside a list inside a list)

Comment: sorry, I meant list. It should match the data structure you shared. Did you encounter any issues when you ran the nested_lookup?

Answer (score 1):

See below (no external lib is involved)

```
data = [
[
    {
        "tweets_results": [
            {
                "meta": {
                    "result_count": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "youtube_link": "www.youtube.com/channel/UCl4GlGXR0ED6AUJU1kRhRzQ"
    }
],
[
    {
        "tweets_results": [
            {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "author_id": "125959599",
                        "created_at": "2021-06-12T15:16:40.000Z",
                        "id": "1403732993269649410",
                        "in_reply_to_user_id": "125959599",
                        "lang": "pt",
                        "public_metrics": {
                            "like_count": 0,
                            "quote_count": 0,
                            "reply_count": 1,
                            "retweet_count": 0
                        },
                        "source": "Twitter for Android",
                        "text": "⌨️ Canais do YouTube:\n\n1 - Alexandre Garcia: Canal de Brasília"
                    },
                    {
                        "author_id": "521827796",
                        "created_at": "2021-06-07T20:23:08.000Z",
                        "id": "1401998177943834626",
                        "in_reply_to_user_id": "623794755",
                        "lang": "und",
                        "public_metrics": {
                            "like_count": 0,
                            "quote_count": 0,
                            "reply_count": 0,
                            "retweet_count": 0
                        },
                        "source": "TweetDeck",
                        "text": "@thelittlecouto"
                    }
                ],
                "meta": {
                    "newest_id": "1426546114115870722",
                    "oldest_id": "1367808835403063298",
                    "result_count": 7
                }
            }
        ],
        "youtube_link": "www.youtube.com/channel/UCm0yTweyAa0PwEIp0l3N_gA"
    }
]
]

ids = []
for entry in data:
  for sub in entry:
   result = sub['tweets_results']
   if result[0].get('data'):
    info = result[0]['data']
    for item in info:
      ids.append(item.get('author_id','not_found'))
print(ids)
```

output

```
['125959599', '521827796']
```

Comment: Question - I have a file, not a string. So when you do ```data = [...]```, you take them in as a string. I am doing a ```content = json.load(file)```

Comment: @Nilima - what you are doing is correct and will lead to the desired output. Give it a try. Just do `data = json.load(file)`